# Variable not being set outside function?

Tags: javascript

This is really doing my head in regarding async i cant get this to work as the summonerData array is not set, i know its probably regarding async but i dont know how to validate it.

```
var summonerName = req.params.playerName;
var summonerData = [];
var summonerIds = [];
var summonerGames = [];
redis.exists(summonerName, function(err, reply) {
    if (reply === 1) {
      console.log('Data Found for Summoner in Redis!: ' + summonerName);
      redis.hgetall(summonerName, function(err, object) {
        summonerData.push(object);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Data not Found for Summoner: ' + summonerName);
      lolapi.Summoner.getByName(summonerName, function(error, summoner) {
        if (summoner) {
          console.log('Summoner was retrieved by API! and Saved to Redis!');
          redis.hmset(summonerName, summoner[summonerName]);
          summonerData.push(summoner[summonerName]);
        }
      });
    }
});
console.log(summonerData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something asynchronously, it means the function is called at some point in the future. Your call to `redis.exists` means at some point in the future, the function you provide will be called. The line after it, `console.log(summonerData)`, is run before the callback function.

Move `console.log(summonerData)` into the function for it to work as you intend.

Comment: Is it possible to access it outside the callback? I would like to res.render at the end

Comment: @Elevant It is not possible since outside of the callback, the information is not accessible. Instead, put the `res.render` inside of the callback as well. If you want access to data that is provided asynchronously, it must all go inside the callback.

Comment: I will mark this as answer since it explains what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `promises`

```
var getSummonerData = function (summonerName) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var summonerData = [];
        var summonerIds = [];
        var summonerGames = [];
        redis.exists(summonerName, function (err, reply) {

            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            if (reply === 1) {
                console.log('Data Found for Summoner in Redis!: ' + summonerName);
                redis.hgetall(summonerName, function (err, object) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    summonerData.push(object);
                    resolve(summonerData);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Data not Found for Summoner: ' + summonerName);
                lolapi.Summoner.getByName(summonerName, function (error, summoner) {
                    if (error) {
                        return reject(error);
                    }
                    if (summoner) {
                        console.log('Summoner was retrieved by API! and Saved to Redis!');
                        redis.hmset(summonerName, summoner[summonerName]);
                        summonerData.push(summoner[summonerName]);
                    }
                    resolve(summonerData);
                });
            }
        });
    });
};


getSummonerData(req.params.playerName)
        .then(function (summonerData) {
                res.render(..., summonerData);
        });
```

More: https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises

Comment: Thanks letting me know about the use of promises however that wasnt really my question